# Using ng-required if ng-show calls for dropdown to be shown

Tags: angularjs

So if I have one dropdown with 4 entries in it and the user selects the second option in the dropdown which then triggers another dropdown or input using ng-show, how can I append an an ng-required now on that dropdown/input using pure angular? Had thought combining ng-if and ng-required, but cannot understand if that will work. Suggestions please?

Thanks much.

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: @VVK - see comment for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ng-required` directive on the second input field with an expression. If the Boolean expression returns true, The field will become mandatory, otherwise not.

```
ng-required="your-expression"
```

If you want to make it mandatory always, Then you just add `required` attribute on the field.

Comment: So if my form is called myForm and the first dropdown is named "selectTarget", and has options of "select1, select2, or select3", then can I simply have on the second dropdown/input as ng-required="myForm.selectTarget.select2 = true"? Make sense?

Comment: You can check the ng-model assigned to 1st dropdown in the ng-required of 2nd dropdown as **ng-required="ng-model-of-1st != null"**